# Angular 2 set animation input from component's class

Tags: html, angular, animation

Is it possible to set the inputs of the style in the states of the animation from the class (or anything inside the animation)?

For example, instead of 'translateX(250px)', do something like 'translateX(input)'. The input would be determined from a something inside the class which will change as a result of an action on the DOM.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'wt-moving-parts',
  templateUrl: './moving-parts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./moving-parts.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('imgState', [
      state('before', style({
        transform: 'translateX(0)'
      })),
      state('after', style({
        transform: 'translateX(250px)'
      })),
      transition('before <=> after', animate(800))
    ])
  ]
})

export class MovingPartsComponent {

}
```

Comment: Github issues are still open for this I guess.